# Why do we use the definite article in "the other"?

Tags: articles

Why in the sentence "One suspect was a male youth, while the other was an adult man." we use 'the' before 'other'. I have to explain its function.

Comment: Because they’re referring to one definite other.

Comment: Would "another" fit your example, and have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

In English ***the*** is the most frequently used definite article.

> We use the definite article in front of a noun when we believe the
> listener/reader knows exactly what we are referring to.

Link: [The definite article: 'the'](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/definite-article)

So, here in the sentence

> One suspect was a male youth, while the other was an adult man.

we use ***the*** because it is being referred to a definite other